# Security Privilege Exception in creating alias in Elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

When we try to execute the below elastic alias swap query with custom user, it throws `action [indices:admin/aliases] is unauthorized` for user.

```
POST /_aliases
{
    "actions" : [
        { "add":  { "index": "test_2", "alias": "test" } },
        { "remove_index": { "index": "test" } }  
    ]
}
```

But with the same user, the following alias creation query works fine.

```
POST /_aliases
{
    "actions" : [
        { "add":  { "index": "test_2", "alias": "test" } }
    ]
}
```

Custom user has all privileges for indices starting with test* (we want this user only to be used for  indices & alias management starting with test)

If we add all indices for this user, then first query works. I don't know why the user needs permission to all indices if I need to delete index starting with test.

Comment: Do you have rules.yaml? Add that also if you have.

Comment: sorry, wasn't sure about rules.yaml. where to look for it and what's the use of it?

Comment: Having the same problem. Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

The user should be assigned a role with the following index privileges:

```
Indices: test*
Privileges: manage
```

This will ensure the user will have all the privileges to manage all the indices/aliases that start with `test`

Comment: provided all privileges (including manage), still only if I provide all indices permission to that user, the first query works.

Comment: Are you managing roles and users through kibana or via APIs

Comment: Managing users and roles through kibana

Comment: Can you share the screenshot for the role settings, that is assigned to the user.

Comment: sorry, I can't share screenshot here. but here are the settings. cluster privilege - all, indices privilege - test* - all